# How to take a backup of database of sql server 2005 in VB.net Using Code

Tags: vb.net

I want to know how to take a backup of database using programatically in VB.net of SQL Server 2005. If you have an idea about it then please send me the code for that.

Comment: I have mentioned an article in my answer which must help you but then you have to come up with the code as per your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

[SQL Server Database Backup Utility using VB.NET and SQL-DMO (New version)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/SQL_Server_backup.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using Sql Management Object. SQL Server Management Objects (SMO) are objects designed for programmatic management of Microsoft SQL Server.

Refer [How to: Back Up Databases and Transaction Logs in Visual Basic .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162133.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form2
    Dim con As SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand
    Dim dread As SqlDataReader
    Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        server(".")
        server(".\sqlexpress")
    End Sub

    Sub server(ByVal str As String)
        con = New SqlConnection("Data Source=" & str & ";Database=Master;integrated security=SSPI;")
        con.Open()
        cmd = New SqlCommand("select *  from sysservers  where srvproduct='SQL Server'", con)
        dread = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While dread.Read
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(dread(2))
        End While
        dread.Close()
        con.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        If ComboBox1.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("select the server name")
            ComboBox1.Focus()
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Try
            ComboBox2.Text = ""
            con = New SqlConnection("Data Source=" & Trim(ComboBox1.Text) & ";Database=Master;integrated security=SSPI;")
            con.Open()
            If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                ComboBox2.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
                cmd = New SqlCommand("drop database " & ComboBox2.Text & " ", con)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                cmd = New SqlCommand("RESTORE DATABASE " & ComboBox2.Text & " FROM disk='" & OpenFileDialog1.FileName & "'", con)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MsgBox("Restore Successfully Completed")
                ComboBox1.Text = ""
                ComboBox2.Text = ""
            Else
                MsgBox("Restore Cancelled")
            End If
            con.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If ComboBox1.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("select the server name")
            ComboBox1.Focus()
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("select the database name")
            ComboBox2.Focus()
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Try
            con = New SqlConnection("Data Source=" & Trim(ComboBox1.Text) & ";Database=Master;integrated security=SSPI;")
            con.Open()
            SaveFileDialog1.FileName = ComboBox2.Text + ".bak"
            If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                Dim s As String
                s = SaveFileDialog1.FileName
                cmd = New SqlCommand("backup database " & ComboBox2.Text & " to disk='" & s & "'", con)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MsgBox("Back Up Successfully Created")
                ComboBox1.Text = ""
                ComboBox2.Text = ""
                con.Close()
            Else
                MsgBox("Back Up Cancelled")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        con = New SqlConnection("Data Source=" & Trim(ComboBox1.Text) & ";Database=Master;integrated security=SSPI;")
        con.Open()
        ComboBox2.Items.Clear()
        cmd = New SqlCommand("select * from sysdatabases", con)
        dread = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While dread.Read
            ComboBox2.Items.Add(dread(0))
        End While
        dread.Close()
        con.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```